# How to use geolocation.getCurrentPosition && geolocation.watchPosition

Tags: react-native

I try to get coordinate when user move 0.1 meter. But even I dont move, it gives me logs and also they are not same values. forexample;

*this is firts values :*

> lat2 : 38.4420875
>   lng2 : 27.1441123

*this is second values :*

> lat2 : 38.4420843
>   lng2 : 27.1441643

**here is my code :**

```
ComponentDidMounth() {

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      this.setState({ initialPosition: position });
      Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                    Longitude = position.coords.longitude;

                    var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
                     var lng = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);

                           console.log("lat :",lat);
                           console.log("lng :",lng);
    },
    (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
    {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1111000, distanceFilter: 0.1}
);

this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((lastPosition) => {

    this.setState({ initialPosition: lastPosition });

    Latitude = lastPosition.coords.latitude;
    Longitude = lastPosition.coords.longitude;

     var lat = parseFloat(lastPosition.coords.latitude);
     var lng = parseFloat(lastPosition.coords.longitude);

           console.log("lat2 :",lat);
           console.log("lng2 :",lng);

},
(error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
{enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 11111111, distanceFilter: 0.1});
}
```

Where I do wrong ?

**EDİTED PART :**

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

this.watchID = Geolocation.watchPosition((lastPosition) => {

    this.setState({ initialPosition: lastPosition });

    Latitude = lastPosition.coords.latitude;
    Longitude = lastPosition.coords.longitude;

     var lat = parseFloat(lastPosition.coords.latitude);
     var lng = parseFloat(lastPosition.coords.longitude);

           console.log("lat2 :",lat);
           console.log("lng2 :",lng);

},
(error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
{enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 250, distanceFilter: 1});
```

*this code in Edited Part is gives me my location in every 10 sec. I added distanceFilter to give me location when I move 1 meter. But it gives me always in every 10 or 15 second. Where I make mistake ?*

Answer (score 0):

You can enable high accuracy by setting `enableHighAccuracy: true`, however as the [Official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation) states `navigator.geolocation` is less accurate in Android as it uses Framework GeoLocation API, instead use [Google Location Service API](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) which both [Google](https://developer.android.com/training/location/) and React Native recommends because it is more battery efficient and accurate.

Comment: Should I use google api ? Can u give me an example or link on web ? Couldnt find good solution

Comment: Use this recommended library it is similar to the RN official one: https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service

Comment: I edited my post and I show what I did. but  I used distanceFilter: 1. So it should give me coordinates when I move 1 meter. But it gives me every in 10 second even I dont move. What is the problem. I couldnt solve this

Comment: @hakan Try this configuration: `{enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0, distanceFilter: 1, useSignificantChanges: true}` You can check the available options [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#watchposition)

Comment: It still gives me coordinates even I dont move.  It should give me coordinates when I move 1 meter then it should stop right ? then if I move 1 more meter it should give me again coordinates. This is what I want but not work like this